# Asynchronous calling a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, delegates, begininvoke

Here is my old code to call an asyn function:

```
    public class Caller {

    public void Calculate(CalcParameters calcParameters, string sourceApp) {
        AsyncCaller caller = new AsyncCaller(_username, _password, new Token());
        caller.Calculated += new CalculatedHandler(OnCalculated);
        caller.calculate(sourceApp, calcParameters);
    }

    protected virtual void OnCalculated(object sender, CalculatedEventArgs e) {
        if (OnCalculatedEvent != null) OnCalculatedEvent(e);
    }

    public void calculate(string calcID, WebService.CalcParameters calcParams) {
        calculate(0, calcID, calcParams);
    }

    public void calculate(long callID, string calcID, WebService.CalcParameters calcParams) {
        try {
            lock(this) {
                Worker wsWorker = MakeCalculateWorker(callID, calcID, new OnCalculatedHandler(OnCalculated), calcParams);
                Thread wsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wsWorker.calculate));
                wsThread.IsBackground = true;
                wsThread.Start();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _log.WriteError(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
            this.GetType().Name,
            MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
            _username,
            ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

But now i need to do this using delegate and begininvoke..

Please can someone help me with this or give me some samples to read from.

Thanks

Comment: So have you made any attempt to use `BeginInvoke` to solve this problem?  Do you know how to define an instance of a delegate?  Are you unable to call `BeginInvoke` on it?  Are you getting an error in your solution?  What exactly do you need our help with?

Comment: i have created a delegate but don't know where to and how to use that delegate and call the begininvoke

Comment: The delegate has a method called `BeginInvoke`.  Call that method.  It has a parameter for a callback to be called when the method finishes.  If you have one, you can put it there, if you don't, you can just pass in a no-op method and a `null` parameter for the argument.  Congrats you're done.

Comment: can you give me a sample code or a link which has something similar.. That will make things easier.. Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at TPL -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: You should make an effort to solve the problem on your own, and come here to SO after you have been unable to solve it after doing some research and experimentation.  It's literally as easy as just calling the method; you seem to think it's way more complex than it really is, which is all leading me to believe you haven't even tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @tucaz Given that he's being asked to do the same thing in a different way, my guess is it's an academic assignment, so it really does need to be done this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MSDN example which explains how to use Asynchronous Delegates.

Read through it but also go through it step by step as if you were the program to understand it.

[Asynchronous Delegates Programming Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80ttd5f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)